# Grouping together data to get highest point per team

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with some data as follows.

**Player 1**
Name - xx
Team - Red
Points - 23

**Player 2**
Name - xx
Team - Green
Points - 20

**Player 3**
Name - xx
Team - Blue
Points - 40

**Player 4**
Name - xx
Team - Green
Points - 20

...and so forth.

I have this so far which just basically lists every player. Simple enough.

```
var item = (from player in playerList.players
orderby player.points descending
select player);
```

Now what can I do to that which basically groups up all the players in the same team and adds up all of their points and displays them overall as a team. So it would basically be like -

Red - 200pts
Blue - 190pts
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply group the members using [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) by their `Team` property and use the [`Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.110).aspx) method to get your totals :

```
// Group each player by the Team property and then associate the
// team name to the total points for that team
var teams = playerList.players.GroupBy(p => p.Team)
                              .Select(t => new { Team = t.Key,Points = t.Sum(p => p.Points)});
// Loop through your teams here
foreach(var team in teams)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{team.Team}: {team.Points}");
}
```

You can [see an interactive example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VOaLgP)

Answer (score 3):

You can group the players into teams using `group By`:

```
var teams = (from player in playerList.players
            group player by player.team into team
            select new { Team = team.Key, Points = team.Sum(t => t.points) });
```

Or using extension methods:

```
var teams = playerList.players.GroupBy(p => p.team)
                              .Select(t => new 
                               { 
                                   Team = t.Key, 
                                   Points = t.Sum(p => p.points) 
                               });
```

Answer (score 0):

[GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is what you're looking for:

```
var result = playerList.players.GroupBy(x=>x.Team)
             .Select(grp=> new {
                       GroupName=grp.Key,
                       Points=grp.Sum(y=>y.Points));
```

Try!